# Issues with Hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap

I am having an issue trying to iterate through a sentence that a user inputs for a matching word in my hashmap. For example if the user enters "I am reading with the professor". Where professor is the keyword. I want to scan the sentence that the user inputs for the keyword professor or it's synonyms in the hashmap. So far when i run my program the code just hangs.

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
/* Initialization */
    HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    synonymMap= populateSynonymMap(); //populate the map
    System.out.println("Welcome To DataBase ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    String[] inputs = input.split(" "); //Here split the sentence to words.

    for (String in : inputs) { //iterate over each word of the sentence.
        if (synonymMap.containsValue(in)) { //check if the values of synonymMap has the string in.
            for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : synonymMap.entrySet()) {
                String[] value = entry.getValue();
                if (Arrays.asList(value).contains(in)) {
                    parseFile(entry.getKey());
                    System.out.println("Have a good day!");
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And my hashmap method:

```
private static HashMap<String, String[]> populateSynonymMap() {
    responses.put("professor", new String[]{"instructor", "teacher", "mentor"});
    responses.put("book", new String[]{"script", "text", "portfolio"});
    responses.put("office", new String[]{"room", "post", "place"});
    responses.put("day", new String[]{"time",  "date"});
    responses.put("asssignment", new String[]{"homework", "current assignment "});
    responses.put("major", new String[]{"discipline", "focus"," study"});


    return responses;
}
```

Parsefile checks a textfile for the word and returns the sentence

public static void parseFile( String s) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File file = new File("data.txt");

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
        if (lineFromFile.contains(s)) {
            // a match!
            System.out.println(lineFromFile);
            // break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: *"So far when i run my program the code just hangs."* And where? Have you tried to debug your code? And what is `#parseFile`?

Comment: if (synonymMap.containsValue(in)) - Should this be if (synonymMap.containsValue(input))?

Comment: @DanW He wants to check single words, not the whole sentence at once.

Comment: @Tom i want to check a sentence for a keyword.

Comment: @Curtis No, that line of code that Dan W posted has a different purpose.

Comment: You don't need a `Map` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the types of input and synonymMap in your code:

```
HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
// ... more code ...
for (String in : inputs) { //iterate over each word of the sentence.
```

So, this will always return false:

```
if (synonymMap.containsValue(in)) { //check if the values of synonymMap has the string in.
```

Now, you need to:

> scan the sentence that the user inputs *for the keyword professor **or** it's synonyms in the hashmap*.

That tricky 'OR' means you need to check both in key and values for a match, since key values are not in their list values as it would be redundant. So inside `for (String in : inputs)` you should have:

```
boolean found = false;
for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : synonymMap.entrySet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String[] value = entry.getValue();
    if (key.equals(in) || Arrays.asList(value).contains(in)) {
        found = true;
        parseFile(key);
        System.out.println("Have a good day!");
        break;
    }
}
if (found) {
    break;
}
```

Comment: Well, if you're going to do this, then you don't need a `Map` at all to begin with.

Comment: Yes, he needs it because if all synonyms were together, he could not be able to know which of them is the key that `parseFile()` needs

Comment: @biomorgoth This works but only if the user enters one word. I want it to work so that if the user enters a setence it would check that sentence for the word.

Comment: No, OP doesn't need a `Map` at all. You can do this fine by using a `List<List<String>>` and having the first entry of the inner `List<String>` as the desired keyword. Just check what you're doing in the code, the key is really useless if you're always going to iterate through all the keys. This implementation defies the use case of the `Map`.

Comment: @Curtis sorry, it was the `break;` after the inner for. Without it, you should be fine. I edited the answer to remove the extra `break;`.

Comment: You are right @LuiggiMendoza, your approach with the `List<List<String>>` with the first entry as the "key" is also valid. The Map solution just makes it look more elegant as it keeps the "main keyword" clearly differenciated.

Comment: It's not elegant at all, and you're not even taking advantage of it. Anyway, this answer somewhat solves the problem, but the problem is OP's bad design.

Comment: @Curtis sorry again hehe, but i knew that `break;` was relevant. It should be there to prevent a case like "I am with the professor and teacher" to fire up `parseFile()` twice (or more depending on input).

Comment: OP can take the List proposal, nevertheless the answer not just somewhat solves, but fulfills the predicate. I'm not refactoring because IDK what else he would be using that Map, so i must adapt to what is existing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line: `if(synonymMap.containsValue(in))`

Since the value of the `HashMap` is an object of type String array it will always return false because you are comparing a String to a String array.

What you need to do is to get the key and then iterate on that key or simply call the contains method:

```
for(String in : inputs){ //iterate over each word of the sentence.
    if(synonymMap.get(in) != null){ //check if the key exist


        String[] value = synonymMap.get(in);
        if (Arrays.asList(value).contains(in)) {

            parseFile(entry.getKey());


            System.out.println("Have a good day!");
            break;
        }

    break;
   }
}
```

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza in the example above there would be no null values therefore it is fine to use the get method.

Comment: @Curtis the key is the `in`

Comment: @luiggi Relax dude Let me learn from my mistakes. Thanks for the advice though

Comment: @Curtis then it is the `parseFile` implementation